# if else-if not working

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have an if else-if block as follows but it works only half-way.The if part works and so does the first if-else. But the last two if-else statements are never getting executed even in cases when they should evaluate to true. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
//Getting current date and time
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);                     
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

//Getting user-entered date and time values.
String[] selected_date_string = date.getText().toString().split("-");
int selected_month = Integer.parseInt(selected_date_string[0]);
int selected_day = Integer.parseInt(selected_date_string[1]);
int selected_year = Integer.parseInt(selected_date_string[2]);
String[] selected_time_string = time.getText().toString().split(":");
int selected_hour = Integer.parseInt(selected_time_string[0]);
int selected_minute = Integer.parseInt(selected_time_string[1]);

boolean has_error = false;
int error = -1;

//PROBLEM AREA
if (selected_year < year) {
    error = 1;
} else if ((selected_year == year) && (selected_month < month)) {
    error = 2;
} else if ((selected_year == year) && (selected_month == month)) {//this part doesnt work no matter what I do!
    error = 3;
} else if ((selected_year == year) && (selected_month == month) && (selected_day == day)) //this part too!
    if (selected_hour < hour) 
        error = 4;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with debugger attached to ensure that values are what you think they should be?

Comment: How could the last "else if" block *ever* execute, given that it's got the same condition as the previous one?

Comment: need to lean basic fundamental of the if else ....

Comment: just check your 3rd else if write properly of the value of year month and day because it is duplicate?

Comment: Thanks everyone! Although I do admit the code is rather shoddy, @Andreas_D , @RamonBoza and @DEVANG SHARMA are right...the problem was not with the block itself rather with the values of the months being compared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually we forget that `MONTH` in `Calendar` is zero based, in other words: the value for january is `0` and not `1`, as we expect..

You may have to decrement your `selected_month`...

---

use this line in your code:

```
int selected_month = Integer.parseInt(selected_date_string[0]) - 1;
```

Comment: or `int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;`

Comment: Thanks the month was the issue! :)

Answer (score 4):

You have a duplicate statement:

```
else if ((selected_year == year) && (selected_month == month))
```

The last one will never be evaluated because the previous one will already pick it up.  I know the second one is more specific, but that won't matter.  For example, if your years match up and your months match up, it won't matter that your days do too because the first statement that becomes true is your `error = 3` else if statement.

As for why neither of the bottom two statements get evaluated, I believe @Andreas_D is onto it when he mentions that the month is a zero-based value.  It may be that the statement is working, just not as you expected.

Comment: There's no duplicate expression, the code is just poorly formatted. The last one that looks like a duplicate actually has a third equality test on the next line.

Comment: @jpm - it doesn't matter since the second one will be evaluated to true before it gets to the third one.  As I said, I knew the second of the two statements was more specific (it had a third test) but that won't matter.  If the two statements were swapped, it would matter.

Answer (score 3):

Calender class in Java returns 0-11 for month,

so if current month is Jan then it returns 0

for feb 1 as so on,

for December it returns 11

so your if condition never equals any way

check it

comment or reply if any issue regarding it

Answer (score 2):

You should put the most specific condition as the first if. The last if can't execute as its condition is more specific than the 3rd one ( (selected_year == year) && (selected_month == month) ) but that first part returns true for the 3rd one before the last one get checked, so you'll never get the last if to execute even if it's true for the last part ( selected_day == day ).

Putting that condition as the first one would make sure it will get checked.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `switch case` construct instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I execute this piece of code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

result it:

```
day = 28
month = 5
year = 2011
hour = 15
minute = 24
```

So maybe you are passin 06-28-2011 to test it and never got correctly compared, so if I print out error at the end with "07-11-2011" and "18:00" it print -1

When I use it with "05-11-2011" it prints 3

my suggestion is to change

```
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

to

```
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
```